# Closing a view after cancelling an email

Tags: iphone, email, ios6

I want to be able to send an email from my app, in which I have got that portion working. The problem is when I cancel sending an email (which is what I'm testing for now) the email part is dismissed but I'm left with a black screen which I can't seem to dismiss.

So this is what I have. I've created a class to handle the email part:

MailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface MailViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>


@end
```

Implemented as follows:

```
#import "MailViewController.h"

@interface MailViewController ()

@end

@implementation MailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mailer setMailComposeDelegate:self];

        [mailer setSubject:@"Subject"];
        NSMutableArray *toArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email@gmail.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toArray];

        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failuer" message:@"This device is unable to send emails" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

    switch (result){
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email was sent");
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed");
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent");
            break;
    }

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

And all of this is shown from another view like so:

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Going to send an email....");

    MailViewController *mail = [[MailViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mail animated:YES];


}
```

So when I run all of this, the email program opens and I can do email stuff. I can select Cancel, then Delete Draft and the email program is removed. However, I'm left with a black screen which I can then select Back from the top navigation bar to return to the previous view.

I simply want the app to return to the view that shows the email program when an email is sent or cancelled (or whatever). I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is tat you are `pushing` a MailViewController and then `dimissing`, if you `push` you should `pop` the view controller.

`MFMailComposeViewController`s should be presented modally, not pushed on the navigation stack. You also dont need a subclass, you can create an instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` directly:

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Going to send an email....");

    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

    switch (result){
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email was sent");
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed");
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent");
            break;
    }

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: He is presenting it modally, from the subclass. Agreed on the lack of need for the subclass.

Comment: Fantastic! I did exactly what you recommended, got rid of the subclass moving the -(void)mailComposeController and added the email stuff to my -(IBActionsendMessage in my "main" view and made it the delegate.

Everything works as it should! This is my first iPhone App so I'm sure there are a lot of newbie mistakes, but we got to start somewhere I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple architecture questions I have, but first - the TL;DR version:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

You could also choose YES for the boolean, but judging on your implementation, that wouldn't result in something nice. Put that in the delegate call for completion.

However, why not just have whatever's pushing MailViewController onto the stack handle the job of being the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate? You're doing nothing here that requires a completely new view controller be pushed onto the stack.